# Text disappearing when scraping webpage

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to scrape some transcripts ([example here](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/05/07/podcasts/ezra-klein-podcast-elizabeth-warren-transcript.html)) to make a visualization. One piece of information I'd like to avail myself of is who is speaking. Unfortunately, when I scrape the site, this information disappears.

Briefly, here's the situation.

Here's an example snippet of what the reader sees on the site:

```
EZRA KLEIN: Bribery can be effective as a parent. You think you’re not going to do it, and then you do.

ELIZABETH WARREN: Yeah.
```

But when I scrape the site I get

```
[n] Bribery can be effective as a parent. You think you’re not going to do it, and then you do.

[n+1] Yeah.
```

This is after using the following pipeline to get this into R:

```
read_html('[insert_html]') %>%
   html_elements('p') %>% 
   html_text()
```

(All the functions come from the `rvest` package)

Any idea how this is happening / what I can do to preserve the association of speaker and utterance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load this page via `rvest::read_html` the website assumes that you are in a browser that does not support javascript so the page layout will be a "noscript" one, *not* the one you will see if you browse to the page in a desktop web browser.

To retrieve the speaker name try:

```r
read_html('[insert_html]') %>%
   html_elements('dl > dt') %>% 
   html_text()
```

To retrieve the associated utterance try:

```r
read_html('[insert_html]') %>%
   html_elements('dl > dd') %>% 
   html_text()
```

Comment: br00t, thanks so much! When I first saw this solution I thought it was going to be a headache aligning utterance with speaker, given the frequent <p> elements that don't have a visible speaker. But, much to my amazement, your solution works perfectly. Do you mind ELI5'ing how that happens?

Comment: My pleasure, Justin. Basically: rvest is not a full-fledged web browser that can parse a javascript-enabled web page. When you request a page from a site with `rvest::read_html`, the site detects your rvest client as one that does not have javascript enabled so it serves you the plain html version of the page. In other words: requesting a page with `rvest::read_html` is roughly equivalent to opening the page in Firefox "Reader" view  or Chrome "Reader" mode. When you open it in a real browser, you get the full javascript enabled version of the page and the CSS and html may be quite different.